# How to share image + text both to WhatsApp from flutter app

Tags: flutter

I try to use this package
[share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus)
from flutter to make user can share image + text with other apps (WhatsApp). It works fine on Android, but the problem is in IOS I can't share image and text same in one time. I searched for a long time but could not find a solution to this problem.

Code:

```
  Future ShareImage()async{
var urls='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png';
final url=Uri.parse(urls);
final res =await http.get(url);
final bytes =res.bodyBytes;
final temp = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final path ='${temp.path}/imageToShare.jpg';
File(path).writeAsBytesSync(bytes);
Share.shareFiles([path],text:'Great picture'); }
```

Anyone have a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score -3):

I think you need these packages for your need according.

1. whatsapp_share2: https://pub.dev/packages/whatsapp_share2
2. whatsapp_share: https://pub.dev/packages/whatsapp_share
3. akvelon_flutter_share_plugin:
   https://pub.dev/packages/akvelon_flutter_share_plugin
4. flutter_share: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share

More package available at https://pub.dev